# SQL query about competitors and placings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm really at a loss for a good title, suggestions are welcome.

I have two tables, one is a table of competitors, the other is a table with three fields

- event
- competitor
- placing - a number representing what place they got at the given event

My goal is, given a set of placings, return all the competitors that achieved that placing at least once at any event.

So, for example, I might want to see all the competitors that placed 1st or 2nd at *something*.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (if you show what you have attempted then we can steer you in the right direction; it would probably help to include the full table definitions).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your tables are defined
But could try this sql

```
SELECT 
        c.id, 
        e.event, 
        e.placing
FROM competitor_table c
LEFT JOIN event_table e 
       ON e.competitor_id = c.id
WHERE e.placing in (placings_set)
 GROUP BY c.id,e.event, e.placing
```